# how correctly to end all process of program

Tags: c#, winforms, process, kill

my program has event `onClosing` - just hide it. But also i need to implement closing of programm - try to use context menu of task bar notification item.

code:

```
    private void FormMainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //canceling closing form
        e.Cancel = true;
        //hide form 
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //hide icon from tray
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        //get current process
        Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        //kill it and close programm
        proc.Kill();
    }
```

but also read a little bit, that `kill()` terminate all work and "kill" the process, think it can be not normal way to close programm - some data can be destroyed or not stored

also try to use `proc.closeMainWindow();` and `proc.Close()` - but no effect on programm - all windows closed, but process still running.

Question: are `.kill()` it's a correct way to close programm, or ther is some another way to do it?

Comment: It is same if you kill it from Task manager. Is it correct way?

Comment: Are you using foreground threads? If not use `Application.Exit()`

Comment: Another option: `Environment.Exit(0);`.

Comment: `Application.Exit()` - try it - only close all visible windows, but process still working

Comment: Does your program create any background threads? If so you need to notify them that you are shutting down, so they can exit gracefully.

Comment: @Surfbutler realy never work with threads.. how to know how many thread have my programm - in code i dont create any additional thread

Comment: If you don't explicitly create any, then don't worry. The answer posted by @nvoigt will do just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just call `.Close()` in your menuitem click and set a boolean flag so that the OnClose handler can check that flag and know that it should *really* close. That would be a lot safer than trying to kill your own process.

```
private bool onlyHideOnClose = true;

private void FormMainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.onlyHideOnClose)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}

private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.onlyHideOnClose = false;
    this.Close();
}
```